# Tracking , security

Tags: transit, public-transport, travel-tools

I bought my bf a bus ticket but he left his phone in a bathroom and we've been bickering can I find out if he Ever got on the bus
It was in his name with his card

Comment: Could you tell us what are you expecting from this post?

Comment: We don't know which bus company is involved, or even which country this is taking place in. Some bus companies may have a system to scan tickets and report their use to a central database (and depending on their policies, they may or may not be willing to tell you anything about its use), while others simply don't use that kind of technology and have no way to track the use of tickets. Either way, we'd have no idea and you'd need to contact the bus company to even ask.

Answer (score 6):

Without a reasonable legal reason, and almost certainly a court order or at least some involvement from the police, any positive response by a bus company, travel company, phone provider or cctv holder would be a monumental breach of privacy.

If you are worried about your partner, if you feel he isnt in a right state of mind or are worried about his intentions, ***contact the police***.  You do not have to wait a period of time before declaring him missing, the police will actively investigate and carry out welfare checks for any persons of concern if there is credible reason to do so.